# How do I minimize the parameter panel in SSRS?

Tags: reporting-services, report-viewer2010

I have a program that pulls a SSRS report. I know that I can prevent the parameter panel from being displayed completely, but that's not what we need. I need to programmaticly minimize the parameter panel, but still have it available to the user if they want it.

I could always add another button that shows or hides the entire panel, but this seems to be a bit sloppy.

Using the standard reportViewer control, how can I have the report viewer just start with this panel minimized?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Have you tried setting the `ReportViewer.PromptAreaCollapsed` property to `true`, which seems to control this action?

[MSDN entry for ReportViewer.PromptAreaCollapsed](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/microsoft.reporting.winforms.reportviewer.promptareacollapsed%28v=vs.100%29.aspx).

Comment: Actually, I completely missed this. I feel a bit dim, but I appreciate the answer. :) :)